# Compare identity of COM objects in VBA

Tags: vba, com, identity

In C++ if I want to know if two COM interface pointers p1 and p2 refer to the same component, I would do:

```
bool IsSame( IDispatch* p1, IDispatch* p2 )
{
    IUnknown* pUnk1;
    p1->QueryInterface( IID_IUnknown, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pUnk1) );
    IUnknown* pUnk2;
    p2->QueryInterface( IID_IUnknown, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pUnk2) );
    return p1 == p2;
}
```

How can I do this in VBA? I would like to use it for two MSForms.ListBox objects:

```
Private Function IsSame( p1 as MSForms.ListBox, p2 as MSForms.ListBox )
    ' Comparing p1 and p2 would compare their default Property, which is their Value
End Function
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Woops, I accidentally downvoted. I made an edit and then rolled it back so that I could upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Is` to compare two objects:

```
Private Function IsSame(p1 As msforms.ListBox, p2 As msforms.ListBox)
IsSame = p1 Is p2
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, and one more note: If you want to use the Select statement, then Select p1: Case Is p2... results in compile error, while Select p1: Case p1 Is p2... means that p1 is compared against a value of True or False, so the correct form is Select True: Case p1 Is p2...